# os.walk certain file types into an existing ZipFile?

Tags: python, file, copy, zip

Basically I need to copy all files of a certain type within a folder into a `ZipFile` at the highest level (so not within a folder).

For example I have a folder, 'A Folder' and within that folder are a load of .png files. I want to copy all those files into an existing `ZipFile`. Currently I can only get the Folder to copy as well, so I end up with `'ZipFile\A Folder\lots of .pngs'` rather than `'ZipFile\lots of .pngs'`

The code I'm using to move the files and folder is:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('A Folder'):
    for f in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root, f)
        myzip.write(fname)
```

Another quick thing, how would you go about deleting a folder from within a `ZipFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the python docs, the [zipfile.write()](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) method supports a second argument that is the destination name (ie the name in archive), try tto use it like this :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('A Folder'):
    for f in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root, f)
        new_path = os.path.normpath(fname.replace('A Folder', ''))
        myzip.write(fname, new_path)
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks a lot! I didn't realise you could chance the archive destination, exactly what I was after thank you. Only problem is if you run it a second time, it doesn't overwrite the files, it just adds another copy of it, I'll look into it though. Thanks again